# Comparison between Officer and Reporters package for R

Tags: officer

I have some questions regarding the Officer and Reporter packages for R. I am working to automate word document generation and have started using Officer. My searches indicate that there is more written about Reporter on the web and that the package may have been under development for a longer period.

This leads me to ask whether there are any major formatting limitations in Officer compared to Reporter when producing Word documents? For example, I cannot see a function for adding page numbers in Officer.

A second question is to what extent are the packages cross-compatible? e.g can one use functions from Reporter in Officer, or find an equivalent function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.